# How to derive mass term for fermions in $SU(2)\times U(1)$?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, higgs

We have a 4 element higgs field representation:
$$\phi=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}
\phi_1 + i\phi_2\\
\phi_3 + i\phi_4 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
it has a certain potential shape. Which looks like a hat. Potential has a non zero minimum value. Then if we find the higgs field at one the the minimums it will be like this:
$$\phi=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
v + h
\end{pmatrix}$$
I did not understand the terms in this one. I only get that vacuum expectation value is non-zero but what exactly is $h$? why the upper term is 0? Then, I have no idea what happens in between and we get yukawa coupling term and we see mass term for fermions.
Is there a explicit calculation I can follow how the mass term in the Lagrangian is derived? Even though I might not understand I would love to see it. I appreciate every bit of help

Comment: Go to your book.   The second expression for $\phi$ you wrote is not even wrong! $\langle \phi\rangle $ has the Higgs degree of freedom, h  , vanish. Your first expression is variable/changed to $\phi_3\equiv  v+h$...

Comment: @CosmasZachos can you suggest me a book where I can find an explanation and the full derivation ?

Comment: Most books on the standard model cover this. There is one by Griffiths; Perkins; M Schwartz; Li-Fong Li & Ta-Pei Cheng, etc... and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_the_Standard_Model#The_Higgs_mechanism)....

Comment: @CosmasZachos The link you provided does not show the derivation. I did not have access to many books, but will try to reach to the ones you have mentioned, thanks.

Comment: Let me know if all the sources suggested fail you.